# is auto increment looping in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to set an auto-increment id every time someone connect to my site.

But when a user reload or quit, i want to clear info related to that user id and match a new user with this id **instead** of create a new id. 
New id are created when the current user/id list is saturated.

If I'm not mistaken, MySQL auto-increment option in phpMyAdmin just auto-increment. Do you know if there is a way to set it directly like i want when auto increment is checked ?

PS: I dont want random id. I want to put PHP loops to split users and it would be easier if i use a linear id pattern.

thanks

Comment: What you want to do is useless. Instead you need to describe what you want  to do with splitting users.

Comment: hmm i think you want to store the the .auto increment id  with Unique.. and then you check if same user is again come to your site then check .. user is already with than dont again provide id .. hmm

Comment: i have develop a very nice and simple algorithm to split those user into rooms and it fit perfectly with this id system. I know i can give users a number that do the same thing related to a random id. but if the id does it directly its better.

Comment: what i need is a loop that scan an id array, if every id is related to a connected user, then another id is created with auto increment. else, the user match with the first deserted id found in the loop.  I just dont know where's the best place to set this loop. its why i ask if i can modify directly the auto-increment property in phpmyadmin.

Comment: autoincrement should only be used to create surrogate keys. You should not depend on the numbers in an autoincrement column to have any specific meaning other than uniquely identifying a record.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the next available ID in the database somewhere, which starts at 1. When you assign an ID to the user, you assign the next available ID, then increase the "next available ID" until no one currently has that ID. When you remove a user, if the user's ID is smaller than the next available ID, you update the next available ID to be that removed user's ID. For example:

- NA-id = 1
- Add User1 (id sets to 1, NA-id = 2)
- Add User2 (id sets to 2, NA-id = 3)
- Add User3 (id sets to 3, NA-id = 4)
- Remove User 2 (id was 2, less than 4, so NA-id = 2)
- Add User4 (id sets to 2, NA-id tries 3, but already taken, so goes to 4)

etc...

Comment: thanks for the reply, very smart way. I think i can do a loop like that (aproximative language):
for ($i=0; $i < $idArrayLength; $i++){ if ($idArray[i] == void) { $id = $i; $idFinded = true; break;} else {$idFinded = false; continue;}} if($idFinded== false){array_push(); $id=idArrayLength;}

Comment: its a nice idea and I appreciate a lot but I think the loop just above is simpliest. Also its not really answering the question. I would like to thumb up your post but I dont have the required reputation score.